# Matlab - extract pixel RGB value from multiple images at once

Tags: image, matlab, rgb, pixel, spectrum

I have about 2300 images that I'd like to extract the pixel value of each for at the 0,0 location.  I would then like to take those pixel values and create a colour spectrum with them in order from lightest to darkest (or vice versa).  Where there are multiple pixels of the same RGB value, the band should be thicker (I want them each counted individually to show its prevalence).  Each image is the same size.

I'm very new to Matlab, if you could provide step by step instructions that would be great!

Comment: where is your question?

Comment: You have to create a for-loop which iterates over all images. To do so you have to use the `dir` function to list all images. To read images you have to use the `imread` function. To get the first pixel you probably have to read the documentation pages about matrix indexing and the `colon` operator. If you experience problems implementing this, please describe them in detail.

Answer (score 1):

You could start with something like this:

```
IMAGES_DIR = '.'; % path to your images
IMAGES_EXT = '.jpg';

files = dir(IMAGE_DIR);
image_count = 0;
for i = 1:length(files)
    [~,~,ext] = fileparts(files(i).name);
    if(strcmp(ext,IMAGES_EXT)) 
        image_count = image_count + 1;
        im = imread(fullfile(IMAGE_DIR, files(i).name));
        pixels(image_count) = rgb2gray(im(1,1,:));
    end
end
hist(pixels, 0:255)
```

- `dir(path)` returns a list of structs, with info on the files in the directory. The `.name` reads the `name` property of the struct.
- `fullfile` allows to restore the path to the file itself by concatenating directory and file.
- `image_count` is a separate counter (I don't use `i`) because there will be less images than files scanned (even if all images are elligible you still have `.` and `..` in the output of `dir()`).
- `imread` loads an RGB image. R, G, B are stored in a third dimension, so `im` is of size [h,w,3].
- `pixels` is an array in which we store only the first picture of each image, and `im` is replaced at every iteration for memory efficiency.
- `rgb2gray` computes luminance by applying the standard formula `0.2989*R + 0.5870*G + 0.1140*B`. It expects the last dimension of the input data to be of size 3. Here, we pass a 1x1x3 element (RGB of first pixel).
- MATLAB will warn you that `pixels` changes at every loop and that it would be more efficient to preallocate. In this case I don't care as the `imread` will already take much more time than the overhead of resizing `pixels`.
- If you want to plot the occurrence of each value you could do a histogram with `hist`.

I made an assumption of what you mean by brightness, here I assume you mean luminance. Your luminance is a value between 0 and 255 so your histogram bins can be forced to 0:255 which is one way of specifying histogram bins.

Note: as you may have noticed MATLAB is 1-based indexing, not 0